# Nodejs SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: node.js, express

I'm following a tutorial and I can't undestand this error, since I've double checked, pretty sure is my newbieness attacking again...

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:138:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:199:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting.
```

..

```
module.exports = function() {

  this.getNoticias(connection, callback){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM noticias', callback);
  }

  return this;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes `this.thing(...){...}` is invalid. What were you trying to do ?

Comment: `this.getNoticias = function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression you used to declare a function is invalid.

In order to declare a function, you should use `this.getNoticias = function(...)`

So the complete code should look like this:

```
this.getNoticias = function(connection, callback){
    connection.query('select * from noticias', callback);
}
```